# How to disable flycheck fringe markers for warnings?

Tags: flycheck, warning, fringe

I find the question mark fringe markers for flycheck warnings slightly distracting.  Is there a way to hide them?

I'd like to keep the error fringe markers.

I tried `M-x customize-face <RET> flycheck-fringe-warning <RET>`, unchecking all the attributes, and setting the state to 'Save for future sessions'.  That had no effect I observed.

Comment: I ended up just disabling a big list of flake8 warnings so that they were never raised in the first place (which doesn't answer this question)

Comment: Do you mind providing the file you used? you can submit it here: https://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 3):

as a workaround I make it invisible by

```
(set-face-attribute 'flycheck-fringe-warning nil :foreground (face-attribute 'fringe :background ))
```

similarly, I removed the underline with

```
(set-face-attribute 'flycheck-warning nil :underline nil)
```

Comment: for spacemacs user, add this to dotspacemacs/user-config

Answer (score 2):

```
(setq flycheck-indication-mode nil)
```

[Relevant docs here](https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/error-reports.html).

Comment: Yes, I found that -- but I'd like to keep the error fringe markers -- just not the warning fringe markers